# Modify objects before sending to client(Parse Dirty Objects)

Tags: parse-platform

I am getting below error when I modify an array of objects before sending them back to Client. I need to modify this array in order to create a list for section headers.

```
Result: Error: Cannot create a pointer to an unsaved ParseObject
at n.value (Parse.js:12:4222)
at n (Parse.js:14:607)
at Parse.js:14:374
at Array.map (native)
at n (Parse.js:14:351)
at Object.r.default (Parse.js:14:1071)
at Object.b._encode (Parse.js:11:15607)
at Object.success (<anonymous>:156:42)
at e.remindersQuery.find.success (main.js:278:22)
at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:12:27827)
```

The trick to avoid dirty objects was to use below code.

```
object.dirty = function() { return false; };
```

or

```
results.dirty = function() { return false; };
response.success(results);
```

This doesn't seem to work anymore with the latest version of Parse(2.2.6).

Comment: Any help on this please?

Comment: Your trick seems to be working for me and has helped me quite a bit so far. Thank you.

Comment: @Benji, glad it helped. It wasn't working for me with the new versions. I ended up cloning the objects which has not given any problems so far.